# Pandas groupby get value of a column where another column is minimum

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe `df` like this:

| region | model | metrics |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tokyo | ARIMA | 0.1 |
| Tokyo | FeedForward | 0.2 |
| Tokyo | DeepAR | 0.3 |
| Osaka | ARIMA | 0.5 |
| Osaka | FeedForward | 0.2 |
| Osaka | DeepAR | 0.1 |

I want to group this by `region` and return the minimum value of `metrics` in each group, as well as the `model` value where the `metrics` is minimum.

The expected result:

```
| region | model | metrics|
| -------- | --------- |----|
| Tokyo    | ARIMA |0.1|
| Osaka    | DeepAR    |0.1|
```

I tried to do it like below, but not sure how I can complete:

```
df.groupby("region").agg({'metrics':'min', ####... })
```

Maybe use `argmin`? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Also a quick option to look at the first row for each group: `df.sort_values('metrics').groupby('region').head(1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the index of the minimum metric of each group and then `loc` with it into the original frame:

```
# not sorting to keep the original order of appearance of regions
min_inds = df.groupby("region", sort=False).metrics.idxmin()
result = df.loc[min_inds]
```

to get

```
>>> result

  region   model  metrics
0  Tokyo   ARIMA      0.1
5  Osaka  DeepAR      0.1
```

(may the forecasting be fun!)

Comment: Very straightforward way and easy to understand. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

How about sort by value of metrics and drop duplicates remaining the smallest one like this.

```
df.sort_values("metrics").drop_duplicates(['region'], keep='first')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby("region").agg({'metrics':['min']})
```